# why does spring's spel have rootObject?

Tags: spring, spring-el

in spel ,if a variable is not prefixed with #, spel will look it in the rootObject.
otherwise, spel look it in the context.

why does spring's spel have rootObject ?
can rootObject be treated as a common variable?
is it just for convenience?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context usually is the same for all the evaluation of that expression.
The root object is volatile. Think about it as an HTTP request body, where context could be a session for that user. So, root object cannot be as a part of the context since and it cannot be treated as a common variable since. It lives just in a scope of the current expression evaluation.